# Why is the Angular router url different than the document location when reloaded when using CanActivate

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have a simple router setup with Angular 2. When I refresh my page the router: Router object has a different value for url than document does for the location.hash property.

So is I say `router.url` I get `"/"` but when I run `document.location.hash` on the same break point I get `"#/thing/edit;name=asdasdasdsa"`

Why does it not recognize this hash? Once the reload is complete it works fine and I have...

```
{provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}
```

Also, I am using a CanActivate Guard.

Answer (score 0):

So far the only solution I have at this point is wrapping the `router.navigate` in a `setTimeout`. I would really like a better option.

Like this...

```
canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
) {
    let nextUrl = route.url[0].path;
    return this.authService.authenticate().map( (message) => {
        if (message["isAuthenticated"]) {
            // TODO: Super hacky
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.authService.navigateToPage(nextUrl);
            });
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    });
}
```